# why the column sums of character table are integers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, characters

There is a well-known result of Solomon which states that sum of entries of any row in $\mathbb{C}$-character table of a group $G$ is an integer number.

It is mentioned in Martin Isaacs [Character Theory of Finite Group](https://books.google.com/books?id=U-HmNAOdnkkC&pg=PA75&lpg=PA75&dq=solomon%20result%20on%20column%20entries%20sum%20character%20table&source=bl&ots=_JlIk1p5Iz&sig=7ykZDIV3feGjyq8yKi12E8axcSc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBWoVChMI7tGj5JecyQIVhRgsCh34tgRR#v=onepage&q=solomon%20result%20on%20column%20entries%20sum%20character%20table&f=false) as a note that the column sums are also integers. My question is that what's the reason of this latter fact about column sums?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $K$ be the Galois field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ generated by the entries of the character table. Then the action of $\operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ on character values permutes the rows of the character table. So $\operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ fixes the sum of each column, which is therefore rational. But the column sums are sums of character values, and therefore algebraic integers, and a rational algebraic integer is just an integer.

Comment: Thank you for your beautiful answer. I didn't expect the problem to have this kind of approach. So I learned something new :)