# Is it possible to have $\sum_{g\in G} \chi(g)=\frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $F$ and let $\rho : G \to GL(V)$ be a representation of a group $G$ on $V$. The character of $\rho$ is the function $\chi : G \to F$ given by
> $${\displaystyle \chi(g)=\operatorname {Tr} (\rho (g))}$$
> where $\operatorname {Tr}$ is the trace.

Is it possible there exists a finite group $G$ and a character $\chi$ of $G$ such that

$$\sum_{g\in G} \chi(g)=\frac{1}{2}?$$

I believe not, but I have not been able to come up with any demonstration of this fact. And is the fact that $G$ is finite important? I mean, supposing $G$ to be an infinite group, would the answer to this question be the same?

Note: Assuming the field is $\mathbb{C}$.

I believe this is not true (finite case), [because the sum of elements in row of character table is a positive integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1699593/sum-of-elements-in-row-of-character-table-is-positive-integer)**(*)**, but in this case, the characters in the table are irreducible, can I conclude the same for a regular character? Since a regular character can be represented as a sum of irreducible characters.

**(*)** But in this case, I don't have that result up to the point of this question.

Comment: The values of characters (of complex representations of finite groups) are algebraic integers.

Comment: @anomaly I cannot use this result, it helped me to understand that it is not possible, but without it I cannot reach the answer to the question.

Comment: Let $g^n=1$, let $\rho$ be a representation, then $(\rho(g))^n=\rho(g^n)$ is an identity matrix, so the eigenvalues of $\rho(g)$ are roots of unity, so $\chi(g)$ is a sum of roots of unity. That's why the values of characters are algebraic integers. Why can't you use this result?

Comment: @Mrcrg: I don't know what you mean. The result follows immediately from that remark.

Comment: $\sum_{g \in G} \chi(g)$ is in fact always equal to $|G|$ times the dimension of the invariant subspace $V^G = \{ v \in V : gv = v \forall g \in G \}$ of $V$. In particular, it's always an integer. This is a special case of the Schur orthogonality relations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_orthogonality_relations

Comment: If $G$ is an infinite group then it's not clear a priori what it even means to take the sum of a function over it.

Comment: Ha, okay, Derek Holt's answer reminds me that I need to specify that the characteristic of the field is zero above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that
$$ \sum_{g\in G}\chi(g)=|G|\cdot \langle \chi,1_G\rangle,$$
where $1_G$ is the trivial character. Thus it is always a non-negative integer. And if you aren't allowed to assume that, then you have to essentially prove that, by showing that your sum counts the number of fixed points in the representation.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is possible.

Let $G$ be cyclic of order $2$, and let $F$ be the finite field of order $3$. Let $\rho$ be the trivial representation.

Then $\sum_{g \in G}\chi(g) = 2 =_F 1/2$.

Incidentally, specialists use Brauer characters rather than ordinary characters when dealing with representations over fields with finite characterits (modular representation theory). One of the reasons for doing this is to avoid this kind of undesirable behaviour.

Comment: Cute, although the OP does specify wanting the field to be $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan As far as I can see, the basic question (which I have answered) is for general fields, and the special case ${\mathbb C}$ is introduced later - the assumption only applies after you have made it!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is helpful. In addition to the remarks above: if $\chi$ is a character of $G$, then $\chi(g)$ is an algebraic integer for all $g \in G$ and since sums of algebraic integers are again algebraic integers, the sum cannot be the rational $\frac{1}{2}$. Now let's look at a proof without an appeal to algebraic integers.

If $\chi$ would be a *class function* rather than a *character*, the situation is different. For example if $\chi$ would be the irreducible character of degree $2$ of $S_3$, and $\lambda$ the non-trivial linear character of $S_3$, then $|\chi|$ is a class function but *not* a character. In fact one can easily calculate from the character table that
$$|\chi|=\frac{2}{3}1_G + \frac{2}{3}\lambda + \frac{1}{3}\chi.$$
Note that $[|\chi|,|\chi|]=[\chi,\chi]=1$, so $|\chi|$ has norm $1$ as with the irreducible characters, still it is not a character! In fact, every class function $\varphi$ can be expressed as $\varphi=\sum_{\chi \in Irr(G)}a_{\chi}\chi$, with $a_{\chi} \in \mathbb{C}$. And here $\varphi$ is a character if and only if $a_{\chi} \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$. Now in your question, you are looking at $|G| \cdot [\chi,1_G]=|G|a_{1_G}$, which hence is always an integer. So fractions will never appear.

So this leaves us with the following question: if $\varphi$ is a class function (not necessarily a character) is always $|G|[\varphi,1_G] \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$? Well, this is not true in general. A counterexample can be found with $G=PSL(2,7) \cong GL(3,2)$, the simple group of order $168$. Let $\chi$ be one of its irreducible characters of degree $3$, and put $\varphi=|\chi|$. Then $\varphi$ is a class function but a calculation shows that $|G|[\varphi,1_G]=66+48\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: When you say "class function", do you mean "class function with algebraic integer values at all conjugacy classes"?

Comment: No, general, a class function from $G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, being constant on conjugacy classes.

Comment: Then your question clearly has a negative answer: A linear form on a $\mathbb C $-vector space will have integer values everywhere only if it is identically zero.

Comment: Hmm, I found a counterexample, see at the bottom of my answer above.